# Ember App.model setting not working

Tags: ember.js

```
   var App = Ember.Application.create({
      loaded:function(){
        async(function(result) {
            data = SomeModel.create(result);
            App.model = data;
            console.log(data, App.model); //Output: <Object>,undefined
        });
      }
    });
```

I have the above code snippet. App.loaded is called from an async call completion. It makes another async call within it.

I am trying to append the response to the **App** itself. But that doesn't work. Data is defined and an *Object* but App.model is *undefined*.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to set 'model' on App as its an Ember.Object

```
 var App = Ember.Application.create({
    loaded:function(){
        async(function(result) {
            data = SomeModel.create(result);
            App.set('model', data);
            console.log(data, App.model); //Output: <Object>,<Object>
        });
    }
  });
```

You cant directly append a key to an Ember Object like

```
App.model = data; // This is wrong.
```